# Managing routing by Link in grandchild component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-routing

I have an App component, that has child component NavigationBar. That NavigationBar also has children, those are NavigationBarTabs. What I want to do, is to manage routing in App component, but have links in NavigationBarTabs. If I do it this way, I can only get new content in App by refreshing. If I keep links in App component it works fine, but obviously I would like those links to be in NavigationBarTabs. Is there any way I can do that? Examples below:
Works after clicking link:

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <Route path ='/Profile' component = {Profile}/>
   <Route path ='/About' component={About}/>
   <Route path ='/Catalog' component={Catalog}/>
   <Link to={'/Profile'}>Profile</Link>
   <Link to={'/Catalog'}>Catalog</Link>
   <Link to={'/About'}>About</Link>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Works after clicking link and refreshing page:

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <NavigationBar/> <--- Tabs with Links are stored there, same 'to' prop
   <Route path ='/Profile' component = {Profile}/>
   <Route path ='/About' component={About}/>
   <Route path ='/Catalog' component={Catalog}/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I wanted my links to be in a sliding side bar. 
here is a way I found worked for me.

Routes Component: I imported the components which i would like to route to into my routes component. As below.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Component from './component.js';

const routes = [
  {
  path: '/',
  exact: true,
  main: () => <place component here/>
  },
  {
  path: '/dogs',
  main: () => <place component here/>
  },
  {
  path: '/cats',
  main: () => <place component here/>
  }
];

export default routes;
```

Sidebar Component: I then placed my links in my sidebar component as below.

```
import React from 'react';
import './SideDrawer.css';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';


const sideDrawer extends Component{

 render(){
  return(
   <nav className='sidebar'>
     <ul>
      <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
      <li><Link to='/dogs'>Dogs</Link></li>
      <li><Link to='/cats'>Cats</Link></li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
  );
 }
};

export default sideDrawer;
```

Then in my App.js component which will render my page I made the following imports:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SideDrawer from './components/SideDrawer/SideDrawer';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import routes from './components/routes/routes.js';
```

Then included the following in my return statement.

```
return(
      <div style={{height:'100%'}}>
        <BrowserRouter>

        <SideDrawer/>
         <main>
          {routes.map((route) => (
           <Route
            key={route.path}
            path={route.path}
            exact={route.exact}
            component={route.main}
            />
          ))}
         </main>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

please note everything inside the App.js return statement is wrapped inside a BrowserRouter tag. Hope this can help you.

Comment: I've solved it by wrapping top component in <BrowserRouter>

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping top component in  solved the problem